# Jquery AJAX call to a void service method showing weired behaviour on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, browser

I am calling a void POST method in my application through the JQuery AJAX block, on IE the service doesn't even gets called however the control lands in the success block all the time.(Tested this using firebug for IE). Does it have something to do with the void service method, Also what should be the way for me to handle this situation.

Appreciate the help in advance!

Vaibhav

P.S. this functionality works fine on Firefox and Chrome

below is the way service is called

```
options = {
    url: url,
    success: function(o){
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
       contentType: 'application/xml'
    }
```

Comment: what is mw? it should be jQuery.ajax(options); on your success you deal with the data like so `success:function(){ $('#result').html(o); }` [if it's html returned as response]

Comment: mw is basically a package where the same Jquery.ajax(options) is called. i dint get the second point you just mentioned.

Comment: mw is pointless, there you just making a page request and get it's contents, after that you deal with the contents your way, success method allows you to deal with your contents and put it where ever you wish, read the api properly and don't skip lines... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i am sorry but u re missing the point here, the problem is that on IE service isnt even getting called and it still land in the succes block, leave aside mw.

Answer (score 0):

IE is a bit too aggressive in caching data and it happens quite a lot that a GET returns previously cached data. Now a POST should never be cached but knowing IE :-(. Try adding a  `cache: false,` to the request.

Comment: Thanks maurice but its more then just the cache my initial thought ws the same but its just doesnt works that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use fiddler and compare what gets sent over the wire between IE and Chrome.